# When a class name is suffixed with Engine, does it mean the same as 'Service'?

Tags: java, c#, .net, oop, naming-conventions

I sometimes see classes where their names are suffixed with 'Engine'. For example: RuleEngine.

I wonder if it stands as the same as Service, or if there is a nuance?

Thanks

Comment: It depends completely on the project/framework.

Comment: Naming conventions aren't something as global rules, so it can vary.

Comment: Very unspecific question (really not "worth" your reputation, imho); so the only answer I can find is very unspecific, too. I think that "engines" typically represent something that processes some input using a "rule set" (which could be changed dynamically). Like a "state machine engine".

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is very subjective to each programmer but here is how I interpret these names:

- Service: (as Daemon or Windows Service), runs continuously but passively, waiting for something to happen or listening to a call. Example : a web service waiting for a request.
- Engine: runs continuously doing something. Example a 3D engine, rendering things

Obviously there is no absolute truth and the name may have been chosen quickly/poorly.

Comment: Neither of them needs to be 'continuous'.

Comment: Of course neither of them needs to be continuous, again this is very subjective, **I** tend to call them like that for these cases. The question is very open, there is no right answer here.